# How to deal with ALSA errors

Tags: linux, python, alsa, error-handling

Using some very simple example code to do speech-to-text in Python it works, but spews out a stream of the following errors and warnings:

```
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:567:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1000:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2675:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2675:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2675:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:1001:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1000:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
...
```

I can suppress this by starting the program with 2>/dev/null. However, this is not a good solution, there is something wrong with the ALSA setup, it looks like.

This is Arch Linux and I have not done anything to my ALSA setup. It works perfectly fine for both recording audio and outputting audio with all software I've tried.

In alsa-mixer I have two "sound cards".

"HDA Nvidia", which is a Nvidia GPU 9a HDMI/DP, this is my "(default)", even though this is not what I actually use for audio.
"HD-Audio Generic", which is a Realtek ALC892, this is what I actually use for audio input and output.

The example code is as follows:

```
# Python program to translate
# speech to text and text to speech
 
 
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3 
 
# Initialize the recognizer 
r = sr.Recognizer() 
 
# Function to convert text to
# speech
def SpeakText(command):
     
    # Initialize the engine
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say(command) 
    engine.runAndWait()
     
     
# Loop infinitely for user to
# speak
 
while(1):    
     
    # Exception handling to handle
    # exceptions at the runtime
    try:
         
        # use the microphone as source for input.
        with sr.Microphone() as source2:
             
            # wait for a second to let the recognizer
            # adjust the energy threshold based on
            # the surrounding noise level 
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source2, duration=0.2)
             
            #listens for the user's input 
            audio2 = r.listen(source2)
             
            # Using google to recognize audio
            MyText = r.recognize_google(audio2)
            MyText = MyText.lower()
 
            print("Did you say ",MyText)
            SpeakText(MyText)
             
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
         
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("unknown error occurred")
```